# Как преобразовать SQL в Laravel-запрос?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть рабочий код :

```
SELECT * FROM painters
LEFT JOIN reviews ON painters.id = reviews.painter_id
GROUP BY painters.id ORDER BY AVG(reviews.rating) DESC;
```

```
    
$painters = Painter::where('status', '1')
    ->when($rating, function ($query) {
        //нужно его вставить сюда (ниже код не работает)
        return $query->leftJoin("reviews", function ($join) {
            $join->on("painters.id", "=", "reviews.painter_id");
        })->orderBy("avg", "reviews.rating", "desc")->groupBy("painters");
    })->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так

```
$painters = Painter::select('painters.*')
    ->leftJoin('reviews', 'painters.id', '=', 'reviews.painter_id')
    ->groupBy('painters.id')
    ->orderByRaw('AVG(reviews.rating) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]